# Are only word sizes used as structural elements in machine computation?

Tags: parallel, computer-architecture, addressing, 3d

**Research:**

I have been looking for some time online. everything i know in-fact.
 ive liked sparse matrix representations, i have found gate level sharing optimization after 'formula reduction' and Inter-Thread Communication Storage.  In parallel processing, in particular machine learning, multiple cores seem so important and there are many papers to this effect. There are so many interesting topics i have found out about that all seem to need this.

**Double barreled Question**

are word sizes are the only standard in machine computation?

word sizes, where 8 bits can represent 256 discrete values and all others are combinations of this standard?
If the first answer is yes, why are structures not used in hardware?

**Structure**
- If a byte had 9 bits i probably wouldnt be asking this question.
An 81 bit wordsize (that is a page, a cube would be better (8 cubes, each 9 pages of 9x9 trits would be even better.)) would allow for any rotation/position/vector etc to relate to each other with simple bitshifts rather than software trig functions. an example use is the 3d game i made using the structure as global reference (with fractal to/from/through micro/macro scaleabilities) in the same project.

\$9(9(3*3)\$ trits to express \$((9^9)^3)^3\$ positions per cube
so, potentially expressing 999999999,999999999,999999999 3 times per cube

\$(1000-n)^(9n)^(45) \$ positions per cube.
\$(1000-n)^(9n)^(360) \$ with 8 cubes.

this is vector representation from 0,0,0 up to +/- 81 decimal digits per plane. a register perfectly fitting that range for **every degree** in the 3 planes.
a full 64  is made of 216 cubes

the structure has a fractal growth of \$((8*27)^(27^(27)^9)^2\$ each repeating layer counting up the power by 1.

**Orientation/Lateral motion**
- trig functions are avoided by my input style. the mouse click controls orientation. dragging horizontally controls roll and dragging vertically controls scale. these are in the RotIn2 sprite. wasdeq controls are lateral motion and rely entirely on the orientation to control distance in each plane; ie W = forward 3 (positive 3 z plane).  the direction script, at the very bottom left of terminal sprite in my scratch project.

set moveX to (abs(-1 +(abs(currentX-180)/90)

set moveY to (abs(-1 +(abs(currentY-180)/90)

set moveZ to (abs(-1 +(abs(currentZ-180)/90)

\this calculates alignment of the current xyz (where x,y and z can each be 1-360)
each is now between 1 and 0 where 1 is a 90 degree tangent to 0

if z plane (forward/back), set X2 to 3*(moveZ-moveX), set Y2 to 3*(moveZ-moveY), set Z2 to 3*moveZ

if x plane (strafe) set X2 to 3*moveX, set Y2 to  3*(moveX-moveY), set Z2 to 3*(moveX-moveZ)

if y plane (vert/drop) set X2 to 3*(moveX-moveZ), set Y2 to 3*moveY, set Z2 to 3*(moveY-moveZ)

set currentX to currentX+X2, set currentY to CurrentY+Y2, set currentZ to currentZ+Z2. \$

**Representations**

Using this structure to represent positions allows representations of triangles very simply. Therefor Regular Polygons. The costumes of sprite 4;
i asked myself

A regular polygon drawn with x=0 y=0 as centre point, in simplex (x>0,y=0)v(x2,y2) of {s}.
"what smallest X gives the smallest digit count(dc()) for dc(x,y,z)+dc(x2,y2,z2)"

if s=4, representing a square's edge, then x=1 and y2=1. 2 active trits of 9. Easily reproduced in 1 byte through a masked Xor gate.

int masksqx128 masksqy16. square|=sqxsqy.  if (byte = 10001000) then it is a square where L= squareroot of 2. As a simplex {4} . simplex are new to me, and awesome, but i have a few ideas as to what else this necessitates mechanically.

if s=5, x=(1+ 2/3) x2=1 y2=1. 4 active trits of 9 (or x=5 x2=3 y2=3. 3 active trits of 27)

in binary coded decimal 
(if(Xor 01010011)=0)and(if(Xor 00110000)=0) then these 2 bytes are a pentagon.{5}.

if s=6, x=2/3 x2=1/3 y2=1/3. 3 active trits. again, 2 bytes of bcd for 6,3,3 to express all that is needed to make a hexagon and from this all further 2d regular polygons can be made as this is a positive equilateral triangle, L=x.

This can be expanded into an edge of a 3d triangular based pyramid, a tetrahedron, when z2=1/3. L=x. This is equally a cone with hight 1/3 and base radius of 1/6 in **4 active trits of 9**. It is possible to express this pyramid in 2 bytes 6,3 and 3,3 for x,x2 and y2,z2 respectively and binary is only just behind by 7 bits, or {3,3} to generalise L.

There is a full representation of a dodecahedron, 12 pentagons = 20 corners = 20 (x,y,z)s, where only 23 trits are active in a single address space with all the required information. what is the optimal expression of a dodecahedron in binary. a Schläfli_symbol? what processes are required to make use of it?

i believe there are many other uses and have been trying to lay [this problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43473/data-structure-for-sparse-matrices-for-an-online-problem) onto the structure most recently.

**OverFlow**

using a representation of .1 to .9 or 1. to 9. probably both, we have a +-81 decimal digits either side of zero in a cube with little effort. a 0. or .0 or even a mid number string of 0 representation could simply be a zero counter. i'd standard 5 trit for up to 10^(162) but potentially up to a 9trit counter.

The neatest way of lining this up with current tech is to split each 8 bit byte into 1 bit for each of the 8 cubes and using 9*81 bytes in representing 8 cubes 
and an insane amount of control code. Accessing a single trit in the structure would add 2 trits onto the Digit or tryte address...

**Addressing**
- In scratch i have not used the adder and gates, only the scratch blocks +,-, abs etc. (but i did build them and the 9bit base 10 bitshift adder with carry)
i have not actually used the trit addressing system, I simply put the x,y,z's into lists and pretended.

1Digit..............1 page...........................9^3trits= 1cube

9trits..............81trits............each page now stacks as a Zco-ord.

.X,Y,Z............Y............Z............................Y

.00 10 20.

.01 11 21...........10...........20

.02 12 22.

.....01...............11.............21........................10

.....02...............12............22.

.

.................... 01

this is the repeated pattern throughout to Address positions

a full 64 (216cubes) can store 5832 decimal digits for each axis in the energy saving 9 bit base 10.

full 64 (216cubes) stores 52487 decimal digits in base 3 (if structure is trits) and a single 1st fractal trit can store 472383 decimal digits.

i say trits because the structure can be more easily addressed by trits
\$((81^(81)^(216))^((6561)^(216))\$ =  the fractal 64 in sprite2 costumes,   20trit address  (1,162,261,467 trits)*3   or  (2,324,522,934 bits)*3 for equivelency= 7 TB at 5 bytes per adress

\$((((81^(81)^(216) ^(6561)^(216)^(6561)^(216)^(6561)^(216)^(6561)^(216)^(6561)^(216)^(6561)^(216)^(6561)^3\$ =81 trits. a page of structure  or  162 bits to address (if wordsize was not an issue).

**Please**
Again, i ask can someone explain what i have done wrong or have misunderstood,  if you have a problem, tell me. do not simply downvote for the question to be deleted leaving me no better off.

I have used a representation/simulation of a structure ([buried in a busy scratch project](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/65130414/)) that can be used to express complicated relations succinctly.
I am asking if anyone had found structures useful enough to build rather than simulate. could structures not simply be a more ordered word size?

For now i think others can make better use of this ([link to scratch profile](https://scratch.mit.edu/users/Illimitable/)) if you can dig out the best bits of my efforts. (i have used 'dimensions' often in my project to mean discrete values.)

Thank you :D

Comment: I'm having trouble making much of your "scratch" possibly because I've never used it before which makes the specifics hard to follow. But does the question mainly condense down to if you could implement trits and/or arbitrary word sizes in hardware and if some devices actually do that?

Comment: largely, yes. but far from arbitrary. currently base2 word sizes are, i believe, the only standard. a necessary one, i understand. the question is more like "has anyone even questioned this standardization's limitations?" how much more energy does it take to keep using this standard for very complicated tasks?  i compare scratch to base2. it makes life very easy for simple things, much harder for difficult things. why keep using scratch? because i already know how to do useful things with it...

Comment: What is "9 bit base 10"? Could you give some examples of this representation? Why use it rather than, say, binary-coded-decimal? Could you give a simple, 2D, *worked example* for how you're handling rotations without trig?

Comment: @pjc50 9 bit base 10 is the energetically lowest representation for decimal i could make up. (abs (-1 +((abs currentZ-180)/90) is the trig replacement. i simply add the mouseclick distance from centre screen to the stored orientation x,y  to look around in exactly the same way as the lateral motion adds onto the stored position as shown. within particular brackets the stored orientation 'looks' at particular quadrants 1-8. i will work on a simple example for you - a working camera is in the project.

Comment: Just an example! What are the "9 bit base 10" representations of 0, 1, and 33 for example?

Comment: 0 is represented by the absence of positive positions. 1 = 100000000  and 33 = 001000000001000000  these are sequential representations of the structure.

Comment: And what is the advantage of this representation? It requires a *lot* more bits than base-2.

Comment: @pjc50 i have edited another example. :D

Comment: One big design flaw you have is that you try to use integer/fixed point math for a case which requires much larger dynamic range, hence is usually done with floats. What will you do when your algorithm reaches an overflow situation?

Comment: @LiorBilia [FP adder actually has more than three steps… 
• Align exponents 
• Add/subtract significands 
• Re-normalize 
• Round 
• Potentially re-normalize again 
• Potentially round again](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~milom/cis371-Spring08/lectures/05_fp.pdf)   could I not choose the bounding error preference up through the fractals? starting with 81 digits "one hot" accuracy with 1 cube. perhaps represent exponents from \$–3^(N–1)+3\$ to \$3^(N–1)–1\$.? all the same stuff with more space right?

Comment: rather than exponents i like the idea of having enough room in the registers (9 trit digits for "one hot") to represent .1 to .9 or 1. to 9. probably both. using these gives me +-81 digits either side of 0 per cube with little effort. i really like the name one hot :D

Comment: .0 or 0. representation could point to a 5 trit counter 10^(2*81) which doubles the supposed number of atoms in the universe.  64bit range is +-308, a cube counter destroys that and could keep the 81 decimal digit precision?

Comment: i could make the .0 or 0. representations incorporate the count. anything more than 10^(6*81) (a 6 trit counter) gets a pointer. wont happen often as far as i know.

Comment: Again, you're using a *lot* more memory to achieve this (729 bits for 81 decimal digits?), and gaining nothing from the pseudo-decimal encoding. If you're willing to have variable-length numbers, the traditional solution is called "bignums".

Comment: @pjc50 i do not think you are taking into account how much more overall mechanical work is needed when you minimize the representation's memory regardless of what you want to do with it.. thank you for the names.

Comment: @Illimitable I'm the one who used to work for a chip optimisation startup. You're the one who's not providing clear quantified comparisons with the existing technology. You've not even defined "mechanical work" here.

Comment: can i try to compare this to branch prediction then?  [Overall, there are four main levers for controlling the power related to branch prediction: 
 Accuracy: For a given predictor size, better prediction accuracy will not change the power in the predictor, but 
will make the program run faster, hence reduce total energy...](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~skadron/Papers/bpred_power_tc.pdf) -an example of over-optimisation eventually causing more waste than it saves. it is the clear quantified comparisons that i have been looking to learn how to express. have you any suggestions where to look?

Comment: "over-optimisation eventually causing more waste than it saves" - that's not what the abstract to that paper says?
Really you need to first learn enough conventional chip design rather than trying to reinvent the wheel in a dark cave. Then you should pick a metric or set of metrics (speed? chip area? energy?), and a particular set of problems; describe the conventional solution and its cost, and your solution with its cost. Instead you've just gone all timecube on us.

Comment: @pjc50 i am attempting to reduce the Total energy use. please remember that digital has had many years of many thousands of people all refining the processes. not a single one of these refinements change the most basic building block, the word size, only the uses of it. i believe that making the word size a structure (in almost the exact same way bignums are used except that i essentially express a larger word as pages or cubes) allows for uses that i cant even imagine yet. the clear quantified comparisons will show up more favorably in its uses than in the structure itself.

Comment: lol, just like you say. (i didnt see your comment until i had posted mine)

Comment: The neatest way of lining this up with current tech is to split each 8 bit byte into 1 bit for each of the 8 cubes and using 9*81 bytes in representing 8 cubes and an insane amount of control code and masking etc to juggle it all. i dont understand why it is so difficult to see the up shot. the wheel has been made with squares and im arguing, from inside my cave and by feel alone, for triangles.

Comment: @pjc50 the quote from that paper i should have used is "This paper shows that if reducing the power in the predictor comes at the expense of prediction accuracy, hence program performance, this localized reduction may actually increase the overall energy dissipated by the processor by making programs run longer."

Comment: But the underlying question is "how is this representation better than binary coded decimal which fits in four bits per decimal digit rather than nine?" And how is the calculation better than, say, current 3D accelerators using matrix multiplication? Your "representation" section is incomprehensible at the moment.

Comment: @pjc50 i will have to work on a better answer for you but off the top of my head; bcd heats every wire every time. I only heat, when representing integers,  1 of 9.

Comment: I think your understanding of "heating" a wire is the problem here. Constant logic levels of 0 or 1 consume almost zero energy (in CMOS): voltage is present but no current flows. It's only the transition that consumes energy. Plus a small "leakage" component for every transistor that exists in the design.

Comment: @pjc50 by transition you mean change of state or transition along a wire= the same thing= Vdd to ground? so to add 1 to a variable x, where x=7 in binary is 4 state changes. 0111 to 1000? different examples have different amounts. 9 bit "one hot" has 2 state changes per digit regardless of example, excluding carries.  this is far from [Formal_equivalence_checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_equivalence_checking) i know. The pictures really help with the representations of regular 2d and 3d polygons, i thought i did well with the maths. how much space do geometry scripts take up?

Answer (score 2):

Addressing only this...

> Are only word sizes used as structural elements in machine
>   computation?
>
> word sizes, where 8 bits can represent a 2^128 dimension register and
>   all others are combinations of this? If the first answer is yes, why
>   are structures not used in hardware?

8 bits can represent only 256 discrete values. So in what sense can 256 discrete values represent a 2^128 anything?

Furthermore, in what sense can a "word size" (a small integer with an assigned meaning) be considered a "structural element"? (which will be normally understood by your audience here as a gate, or a flipflop, or a higher order construct composed of these - for example a register, multiplexer, arithmetic unit, memory etc)

You will need to clarify these points, and likewise improve your communication of every part of your question, because we cannot answer what we cannot understand.

The rest of the question appears to relate to a coding scheme whereby n-dimensional coordinates can be encoded into a number such as an address, therefore allowing rotations by swapping bitfields ... provided that such rotations are 90 or 180 degrees and thus simple axis swaps - it seems that any such scheme falls apart hopelessly as soon as you need an arbitrary rotation such as one degree or one radian : unless explained otherwise I see no gain from further contemplating the notion.

[Note : if a moderator should deem this not an answer and convert it to a comment : I quite understand]

Comment: thank-you very much for being informative. i am trying to use the words i have read appropriately but have taught myself.

Comment: the rotations are included as an aside. simply an idea of representation that includes any angle and diameter in a single xyz. if read appropriately. you are correct, as written they will not compute correctly.

Comment: Then a suggestion : delete the entire aside, explain the central part of the question, and make it standalone, self-contained, independent of that Adobe Flash website.

Comment: deleted the asides, tried to tidy up presentation but i have kept the links, moving them to the bottom, incase anyone wants to dig in :D

Comment: i have edited what i hope is a more interesting aside. i have read also that simulating a quantum superposition is impossible. i read this after doing it but this is not particularly relevant to the structure, except to add additional tools to manipulate what can be represented, so i'll keep it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think Scratch is limiting you here. In Verilog, when defining hardware, you can have whatever bus width you want. Nine bits? No problem!

Very occasionally you see this in real hardware, such as the PIC's 14-bit wide instructions.

You can also, in conventional computing, just allocate normal power-of-two bytes and words and only use part of them. Or you can pack and unpack bitfields with bit manipulation.

Compression standards often operate on packed bits. H264 for example is a bitstream that isn't necessarily aligned on 8-bit boundaries.

Comment: awesome, i will have to look into bitfields and verilog more. what i have found is that while it is possible to portray whatever i want in most languages; any size register, nine bit busses etc, the actual working of this information is reorganized by the time it reaches the hardware. very clever stuff but at the huge scales im considering this will cause some difficulties or take significantly more time. the bonus of structured 9 bit base 10 is, say, 50 million can be represented entirely by the position of the only active bit - a 1 in the 5th position of the 10's of millions. (2,2,3)

Comment: That's not a bonus, that's a massive disagvantage!

Comment: why is that a massive disadvantage?

Comment: Do you not see why representing a number that could easily be represented with just 32 (or even 26) bits instead with 63 bits that are required for this "bit position decimal" is a disadvantage?

Comment: (Now that you've explained this, it sounds closest to what's called "one hot encoding", which is occasionally used, but not for large numbers)

Comment: In fact, you could even use binary coded decimal to represent 50,000,000 as 0101 0000  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 and still use fewer bits.

Comment: except to compute this representation you would need to use AMBA or some such internal communication to move the entire representation as one word to the alu. in order to add 50 mil to 30 mil i would only need to use up to 9 bits (or the single position), shifting from 001000000 to 000000010. granted, for more involving numbers like (49173469+23541345) there are a few more things to consider but the max carry of base 3 adder is 2. ie (a+b+carry) where each can be up to 9, max = 27. a single trit carry for each 9 bit addition.

Comment: A variable-shift unit is about as complex as an adder. You don't need a full bus protocol like AMBA "within" a design unit, you can just have a bus of wires directly to a suitable unit. This is *why* we're all confused and saying you should learn how digital design is actually done before saying "why don't you..."
For almost arithmetic functions your encoding would use a lot more area than conventional binary.

Comment: it would. im not trying to replace base2 for most arithmetic functions. that would be silly. i am including a base3 fractal unit because it would enable far simpler very complex code. the same reason gpu and cpu are different. same reason ram and solid state are different. they have different uses. having the range available would encourage its use too and i think people would find very many more useful ways of using it than i can come up with. if i can convince someone to try ;)

Comment: I would need an on chip protocol. We cant physically connect every cube directly to every other. it is this layer i have dug down to myself ([i recently found this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3390/how-does-a-computer-work), which would have saved me a lot of time putting all the parts together) I am only now trying to ask about, i know now, the number of wires. it turns out i have to learn how to ask questions.

Comment: i have tried to refine the representations section and have a question that you may be able to answer long before i can figure it out?